# Exception on some older computers with EnsureContextIsEnlistedInCurrentTransaction EF 6.1.2

Tags: c#, entity-framework

My application is using EF 6.1.2. I'm using autofac to register my datacontext as a single instance. Lazy loading is enabled and it's a code first db design.

I've recently been receiving error logs from users on much older systems (6+ years old). I've not been able to repeat the errors even on my old dell core solo 1.2 ghz and 2gb ram running windows 7.)

The exception message is below. They vary slightly but all seem to occur from within custom ui value converters.

```
11/10/2015 14:13:01::Error|MFR.UI.Bootstrap.MfrBootstrapper|Stack Trace: at  System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureContextIsEnlistedInCurrentTransaction[T](Transaction currentTransaction, Func`1 openConnection, T defaultValue)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
at MFR.UI.Converters.EmployeeDisplayNameValueConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Field.ConvertValue(Object value, DataRecord record)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataRecord.GetCellValue(Field field, Boolean useConverter)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.DataRecord.GetCellValue(Field field, CellValueType cellValueType)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.CellValuePresenter.get_Value()
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.CellValuePresenter.InitializeCellLevelSettings(DataRecord newRecord, DataRecord oldRecord, Field newField, Field oldField, Boolean isWithinRecord)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.CellValuePresenter.InitializeField(Field newField, Field oldField)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.CellValuePresenter.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.VirtualizingDataRecordCellPanel.InitializeCellElement(Control element, Field field, Record record, Boolean isHeader)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.VirtualizingDataRecordCellPanel.InitializeCellElement(Control element, Field field, Nullable`1 isMouseOverCellArea)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.VirtualizingDataRecordCellPanel.CreateCellElement(Int32 index, Field field, Boolean useCellPresenter, Nullable`1 isMouseOverCellArea)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.VirtualizingDataRecordCellPanel.VerifyCellsInView(Size elementSize)
at Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.VirtualizingDataRecordCellPanel.ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
at System.Windows.UIElement.Arrange(Rect finalRect)
at MS.Internal.Helper.ArrangeElementWithSingleChild(UIElement element, Size arrangeSize)
at System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter.ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ArrangeCore(Rect finalRect)
... more of the same
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayout()
at System.Windows.ContextLayoutManager.UpdateLayoutCallback(Object arg)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.InvokeOnRenderCallback.DoWork()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.FireInvokeOnRenderCallbacks()
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.AnimatedRenderMessageHandler(Object resizedCompositionTarget)
at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
```

The value converter which is called:

```
public class EmployeeDisplayNameValueConverter : 
   {
    protected readonly Func<IDataContext> Repo;

    protected EmployeeDisplayNameValueConverter()
    {
        Repo = IoC.Get<Func<IDataContext>>();
    }

    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        if (value is string)
        {
            {
                var key = value.ToString();
                var found = Repo.Invoke().Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == key);

                if (found == null)
                {
                    return string.Empty;
                }
                return string.Format("{0}, {1} {2}", found.LastName, found.FirstName, found.MiddleInitial);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Any thoughts or suggestions as to what I could look into? As mentioned, I can't repeat the issue locally myself, making it more difficult - but only seems to be a problem on "older" machines.

Comment: What is the actual architecture of a machine generating the exception? Which version of Windows is running? Is this a 100% repeatable situation or does it occur intermittently? Is there any software running on these machines that may not be running on yours (e.g. antivirus)? User permissions? I am convinced you are looking at an environmental issue over a code issue if it works consistently on a few of your development machines.

Comment: I agree. However, it's been difficult to get any more information about the setups until now. I have just been given remote access to a machine on which the error occurs.

They have always been repeatable. If it happens, it always happens. I was told that it "went away" when they updated from 2gb to 4gb of ram. Not convinced about that though. The app uses only about 200mb max.

Comment: Windows 7, SP1, intel i5-2410m @ 2.3 GHz, 64 bit, 4gb ram. So, pretty decent. 1.7 gb mem used at idle. 
Nothing suspicious found yet.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of right now is the possibility of some race condition between your UI event thread and the EF database context being available for access. Is your dev machine able to connect to the database faster than the clients (lower RTT latency)?

Comment: So, still trying to pinpoint things. I should have mentioned it's a local app db using SqlCompact 4. What I've discovered is that if I reduce the number of records from 500 to less than 100 it works fine on the clients machine. The same 500+ works fine locally. 

I think you're right that there is some sort of race condition. The UI has 3 tabs, each tab has a datagrid. The first displayed tab is the one crashing the app. However, if i quickly switch to the second tab and then back to the first, the crash doesn't occur.